# Retrieving Conditional Probabilites for Naive Bayes Model developed using caret Package in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, r-caret, naivebayes

My main question is this:

**How do you retrieve conditional probabilities for a Naïve Bayes model using the `caret` Package in R?**

Background:

I have run a Naïve Bayes Model using the `caret` Package in R. The dataset is essentially health dataset with a binary outcome variable (mistake vs not a mistake) with a series of categorical predictors and one or two numerical predictors. For this, we are using a 5 fold, cross validation technique.

The model runs fine, but I would like to retrieve the conditional probabilities. How do I do this? For example, one of the predictors is "Pulse" which has 3 factors: `Low` , `Normal`, and `High`. I would like to retrieve something like the following "Given a Low Pulse, what is the probability of a Mistake" AKA: 
`p(y = "Mistake" | Pulse="Low")`.

The relevant code is here:

```
ctrl<-trainControl(method="cv",number=5,classProb=T)
mod4<-train(Target~.,data=train,method="nb",trControl=ctrl)
```

In the KLAR package, it's not hard to do (The second line displays this):

```
model4<-naiveBayes(Target~. ,data=train, scale=T)
model4_variable_posterior_prob <- model4$tables[[var2]]
```

However, I'd really like to use the cross validated model that Caret produces above because it's a lot more accurate.

I should note that Caret produces some tables in here:

```
mod4$finalModel$tables$
```

However, I'm not sure if these tables are the conditional probabilities or some other values.

For example, `mod4$finalModel$tables$PulseX2` produces the following:

```
        [,1]      [,2]
X1 0.1343284 0.3415149
X2 0.1731343 0.3789293
```

I believe `PulseX2` is the table for `Pulse= Medium` and `PulseX3` is the table for `Pulse=High`, but I'm not entirely sure. However I do know that in the above, `X1` is a "mistake" and `X2` is "not a mistake" But my question is, is `[,1]` column a "0" value for the categorical factor variable of `PulseX2`? And is `[,2]` column a "1" value for the categorical factor variable of `PulseX2`? So by that logic, is `.3415149 p( y= Mistake (or X1=1) | Pulse = X2)` above the baseline of PulseX1 or something? **Does anyone know what these values mean?**

Alternatively, if there is some way I can retrieve some information on the important individual factors (*not just important variables*) that too would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really about `caret`; that object is created by the `NaiveBayes` function in the `klaR` package. The documentation for that package says:

> `tables`: A list of tables, one for each predictor variable. For each categorical variable a table giving, for each attribute level, the conditional probabilities given the target class. For each numeric variable, a table giving, for each target class, mean and standard deviation of the (sub-)variable or a object of class density.